# UTF-8 to local multibyte with STL

Tags: c++, c++11, utf-8, stl

I need to convert a UTF-8 string to a local multibyte encoding (cp1251) with a multiplatform (Linux, Windows) method. However, I could not find a standard (preferrably STL) method which works on both platforms except first converting (using `std::codecvt` and `std::locale`) UTF-8 to wide character string and then convert the wide string to local string. Is there a way to do this with one conversion?

Comment: 1) cp1251 is not a multibyte encoding 2) Linux almost never uses cp1251, it uses UTF-8 almost exclusively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard library doesn't include anything that will do this. Not directly at least, and one of the components that you'd need is not implemented yet in any C++ implementations: You would use the codecvt facets that can convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16 or UTF-32 and then use functions from the [`<cuchar>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte) header to convert from UTF-16 or UTF-32 to the locale multibyte encoding.

Since that option is not available, your best bet is to either use a portable library, or to implement the conversion yourself using various platform specific APIs, and wrap those with a common API you can use across platforms. You can use libiconv on posix platforms, and MultiByteToWideChar and WideCharToMultiByte on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this out. I think I'll go with two-stage conversion with STL.